# Why Do I have to reload the browser in order that my props are no set as Undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Hi everyone Im having a little problem. Im building an app with react & redux.

So as an example I have a button that its being display based on a comparison
Here is how my code look like :

```
renderExportGuidelinesButton(){
    var { authProfile, guidelines } = this.props;
    if(authProfile.role == "dba"){
      return(
        <button type="button" disabled={this.state.exportGuidelinesBtnDisabled} onClick={this.showConfirmExport.bind(this, guidelines)} id="export-guidelines-btn" className="btn btn-primary">
          Export Guidelines
        </button>
      )
    }
  }
```

In this case the profile role matches and is supposed to render my button.
I have my function bind in the constructor method. Once I reload the browser everything works fine

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your reducer an initial state. http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/InitializingState.html

Or alternatively, you can use [`defaultProps`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops) to set initial values for any prop you want:

```
defaultProps = {
    authProfile: {},
    guidelines: {}
}
```